# Does a secondary battery always charge to its maximum open circuit voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, lifetime

I'm wondering if secondary batteries have a slight open loop voltage drop after multiple cycles. I found [on another forum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505635/dead-battery-voltage-and-its-charging) that a rechargeable battery always has the same open loop voltage after charging, even after lots of cycles, and that the voltage will only drop after the addition of a load. How is it possible that a secondary battery retains its potential?

Hopefully someone can explain what is going on and what the relationship is between cycles, end of lifetime, and open loop voltage of secondary batteries.

-edit- Lithium-ion for example.

Comment: different battery chemistries are different, which secondary system did you want to know about?

Comment: Lithium-ion for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lithium ion battery has a voltage depending on its state of charge (SOC), and on the state of the electrodes.

The terminal voltage of all cells is basically the electrochemistry of the materials, modified by the ionic concentrations in electrode and electrolyte. Unlike lead or nickel chemistries which keep a relatively constant voltage over most of their SOC range, lithium rechargable cells have a very variable voltage.

Charging/discharging involves the physical movement of lithium ions into and out of the electrodes, so the open circuit voltage is strongly influenced by the ionic density in each electrode.

The electrodes suffer physical degradation each time the ions move around, with increased physical degradation and irreversible chemical degradation if the low or high extremes of voltage are reached, which also contribute to a changing open circuit voltage.

Note the lithium cells in satellites are charged to only 3.92 V, rather than the 4.1/4.2/4.3 V (depending on precise type of lithium cell) that commercial earthbound ones are. This gives them lifetime in the decades, necessary when replacing the cell is not an option. Why aren't normal lithiums rated for a lower charge voltage and a longer life? It seems the marketing people decided customers would prefer 500/1000 cycle lifetime with high energy density, rather than 10k cycle lifetime with a lower energy density. Personally I charge my 4.2 V rated cells in my drill to 4.1 V, to increase their cycle life, at the cost of a shorter run time.

Comment: Thank you, has this physical degradation anything to do with the internal resistance of a battery?

Comment: @Joggem Nothing at all.